# React copy query data results in empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, copy, apollo-client

I'm fetching data from BE by using apollo client for react. The data I fetched I want to copy that into a new array, so I can work with the given data. Everything I tried resulted into an empty array.
Does anyone see what I'm doing to continuously get an empty array back?

I tried to map the data and push it into the new array like so:

```
organisation=[];
render(){
return(
      <div  id="public">
        <Query query={GET_ORGANIZATION} variables={{ id }} >
          {({ loading, error, data }) => {
            if (loading) return <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            if (error) return <div>Error</div>
            if (data) {
              if (data.getOrganization.length >= this.organization.length) {
                data.getOrganization.map(company => this.organization.push({
                  id: company.id,
                  name: company.name,
                  street: company.street,
                  addings: company.addings,
                  zipCode: company.zipCode,
                  country : company.country,
                  houseNumber : company.houseNumber,
                }))

              }return (
                <React.Fragment>
                   {console.log("data", data.getOrganization)}
                  {console.log("organization", this.organization)}
                  
                    <div >
                      <p>{this.organization.name}</p>
                    </div>
                 </React.Fragement>
                   )}}
          </Query>

     </div>
)}
```

I also tried it like :
`this.organization = [...data.getOrganization]`

It all comes up.

Comment: are you sure you need this.organisation instead of just organisation

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating the array value after an asynchronous call, so the value should be a "state", so that your components re-renders when it changes. To achieve that, change your organization variable declaration to

```
state = {
    organisation=[]
};
```

and your render method to

```
render(){
    return(
      <div  id="public">
        <Query query={GET_ORGANIZATION} variables={{ id }} >
          {({ loading, error, data }) => {
            if (loading) return <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            if (error) return <div>Error</div>
            if (data) {
              if (data.getOrganization.length >= this.organization.length) {
                setState({
                  organisation: data.getOrganization.map(company => ({
                  id: company.id,
                  name: company.name,
                  street: company.street,
                  addings: company.addings,
                  zipCode: company.zipCode,
                  country : company.country,
                  houseNumber : company.houseNumber,
               }))
               });

              }
         return (
                <React.Fragment>
                   {console.log("data", this.organisation)}
                  {console.log("organization", this.organisation)}
                  
                    <div >
                      <p>{this.organization.name}</p>
                    </div>
                 </React.Fragment>
                   )}}
          </Query>

     </div>
)}
```